# class variables and properties with inheritance

Tags: c#, class, properties

I'm confused about properties in C#, espacially with inheritance:

I have a Pokemon class as an example and want the stats to be protected to modify them in the subclasses (for example at level ups) and I want to read  the stats from outside.

This would be the verbose way to do it:

```
// base class
abstract class Pokemon
{

    // stats

    protected int hp;
    public int Hp {
        get
        {
            return hp;
        }
        protected set
        {
            hp = value;
        }
    }

    // other stats...
}
```

My Question is: Is there a short form for this? Something like:

```
// base class
abstract class Pokemon
{       
    // stats

    public int Kp { get; protected set; }

    // other stats...
}
```

Do these 2 classes work similarly?

I'm confused, because for public getters and setters you write:

```
// base class
abstract class Pokemon
{       
    // stats

    public int Kp { get; set; }

    // other stats...
}
```

And it works like:

```
// base class
abstract class Pokemon
{
    // stats

    private int kp;
    public int Kp {
        get
        {
            return kp;
        }
        set
        {
            kp = value;
        }
    }

    // other stats...
}
```

Which one should I prefer?

Comment: Why are you confused? How would those work differently?

Comment: Why is your backing field `protected`?

Comment: "My Question is: Is there a short form for this? Something like:" Have you tried it out? Of course auto-properties can have different access-modifiers.

Comment: It's protected because the subclasses should inherit it and it should be readonly outside the class.

Comment: You don´t have to make the *backing-field* protected, unless you overwrite the *property* in your derived class and access the backing-field there. Just make the setter protected and you can set the value from anby class deriving from `Pokemon`.

Comment: Sure they work identically.
Simple code is better than complex one. So, use the short form unless you need additional logic inside your getter or setter.

Answer (score 2):

> My Question is: Is there a short form for this?

Yes exactly as you wrote it

> Do these 2 classes work similarly?

Yes, in the first example you can additionally manipulate the field `hp` in the derived classes directly. (personally I don't see the point, you can also make it `private` )

> Which one should I prefer?

That is difficult to say. If you need extra logic to validate the setting of the property use the first option.

```
private const int maxHP = 3000;
protected int hp;
public int Hp {
    get
    {
        return hp;
    }
    protected set
    {
        // extra validation
        if(value < maxHP)
            hp = value;
        else
            hp = maxHP;
    }
}
```

if you don't need it, don't use it